# Unable to generate angularjs table with ng-repeat in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following sample snippet. I would like to show my below `json` object in angular table through `ng-repeat`, which I am generating from my `angular controller` script. I have done the below, but I am not sure why table is not generating and it's data is not showing. Please let me know and I am not sure what is wrong here. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdk8/1rabfgko/9/) available.

Need to get output to smiliar like:

```
Text  IND   US    UK    AUS
No    100   200   170   50
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">   
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var testmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);
testmodule.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.mydata =  [{
    "a": ["IND", "US", "UK", "AUS"],
    "b": ["100", "200", "170", "50"],
    "c": "Text",
    "d": "No",
}];

var mytable= angular.element(' <div class="table-responsive"> <table class="table" ng-repeat="item in mydata track by $index"> <thead> <tr> <td>{{item.c}}</td><td ng-repeat="c1 in item.a track by $index">{{c1}}</td></tr></thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>{{p.d}}</td><td ng-repeat="d1 in p.b track by $index">{{d1}}</td></tr></tbody> </table> </div>');
console.log("mytable: "+JSON.stringify(mytable));
});
```

Comment: What do you expect the console.log to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd put the html on the html page instead of as an element in the controller. Second you were trying to access `p.d` and `p.b`, but those fields are in `item` from your ng-repeat (so should be `item.d` and `item.b`. Looks like this works:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">   
  <div class="table-responsive"> 
      <table class="table" ng-repeat="item in mydata track by $index"> 
        <thead> 
          <tr> 
            <td>{{item.c}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="c1 in item.a track by $index">{{c1}}</td>
          </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
          <tr> 
            <td>{{item.d}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="d1 in item.b track by $index">{{d1}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody> 
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var testmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);
testmodule.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.mydata =  [{
    "a": ["IND", "US", "UK", "AUS"],
    "b": ["100", "200", "170", "50"],
    "c": "Text",
    "d": "No",
}];

});
```

Working Plunker: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4sqsLfgn/1/)

-

**UPDATE:** 
As it seems you want to output your angular element to the console, you should know that mytable is an angular element not a json object so **you won't be able to stringify it...**

Comment: thank you for your response, but i can generate the same in html, but  i need to generate the same in controller only, not in html like above.

Comment: @Sana Your question is quite misleading then, as you say `I have done the below, but I am not sure why table is not generating and it's data is not showing...` then you say `Need to get output` (and then you show the output I provide). What are you trying to accomplish? Seems my answer solves the problem...

Comment: I need to generate my similar output like above table from controller script only, I should not write anything in html file.

Comment: @Sana Why don't you just set up your myData so that you can do an ng-repeat (`a` being the first row and `b` being the second)?

Comment: this looks fine. But actually I wanted to generate the same with angular element only in the controller. In the console.log, I can able to see the generated table with the angular element. I am sorry if I am wrong anywhere. Thanks in advance !